# silverlight for wince6.0

Tags: silverlight

hello 
i want to build silverlight application for wince6.0. im not getting whether we have to use vs2008 r expression blend can you tel me which one is suitable to build for wince6.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Silverlight "sort of" exists for Windows CE (see here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee502198.aspx ) but it's a version programmed via C++ that is, in many substantial ways, different from the Silverlight on a desktop PC, Mac, or Windows Phone 7.

I do not believe there is Blend support for this version of Silverlight, and the Visual Studio support is pretty limited.  In fact, the whole framework is rather limited, as it's based on Silverlight 2, which is starting to feel pretty old at this point.

That said, hopefully the above link helps point you to samples and other documentation that can help.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, Silverlight doesn't support Windows CE 6.0.  You can use the .NET Compact Framework instead, but it doesn't get you XAML or the other cool things that you might have been hoping for from Silverlight.

Comment: This is incorrect - see my answer.  Project "Alchemy" is a version of Silverlight for Windows CE, that does support XAML, but it's sort of weird because it's C++ and rather limited compared to "normal" Silverlight.

Comment: im working with silverlight in wince6.0 how u said that it ll nt support for wince6.0